# Synaptics drivers are not loading on Kubuntu 13.10 on Dell Vostro 2420

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I freshly installed Kubuntu 13.10, 32 bit version on newly purchased Dell Vostro 2420. everything is working fine except scrolling and multitouch features through touchpad.
I am able to change position of cursor using touchpad and able to tap (single click and double click) but scrolling is not working

I tried to find out solution by searching on google but could not find proper solution to load synaptics drivers.

i am listing some details:
Laptop: Dell Vostro 2420
Linux Kernel version and distribution: 3.11.0-12-generic, Kubuntu 13.10

output of xinput list is

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer (3)]                                                                                                                  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]                                                                                                                  
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]                                                                                                                  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]                                                                                                                  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of synclient -l is

Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

output of lshw is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6645687/

xserver log and dmesg dont have trace of synaptics

kindly tell me how to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: How did you install it? Your comments will be a lot of helpfully for me

Comment: @user2981168 I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution at 
http://www.dahetral.com/public-download

downloading and installing this solves my problem :)

Follow these steps and touchpad will be detected by the system

Download file from
http://www.dahetral.com/public-download

Install

1. extract psmouse-alps-1.3-alt.tbz to /
   For this you open Terminal
   run `su`
   Go to the downloaded file folder and execute the following
   run `tar  -xvf psmouse-alps-1.3-alt.tbz`
   run `mv usr/src/psmouse-alps-1.3 /usr/src`
2. run `dkms add psmouse/alps-1.3`
3. run `dkms install psmouse/alps-1.3`
4. `reboot`

Uninstall :
1. `dkms remove psmouse/alps-1.3 --all`
2. delete psmouse/alps-1.3

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Inspiron 3521, but found a simpler solution.  If the system settings tell you that the synaptics driver is not loaded (or not used) when you try to configure the touchpad, simply provide an xorg.conf for it.  Turns out, there is a snippet already made for you.  It is in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d and it is named 50-synaptics.conf. In my case, there was no xorg.conf in /etc/X11, so I simply copied the snippet as xorg.conf into /etc/X11:

```
sudo cp -n /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

If an xorg.conf already exists, make sure it does not already contain the stanzas for the touchpad, and if it doesn't, append the 50-synaptics.conf snipped to the existing xorg.conf using your favorite editor (and sudo).  If it has touchpad stuff in it, you have a different problem.

After re-starting X11 (re-boot would obviously work too), the touchpad worked like a charm.