# Synaptics drivers are not loading on Kubuntu 14.10 on Toshiba Portege R30-A X3300

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, 14.10, multi-touch, synaptics

I am using Toshiba Portege R30-A X3300 with Kubuntu 14.10. everything is working fine except scrolling and multitouch features. 
In the Start-menu > Settings > System Setting > input devices > Touchpad. I see message "Synaptics driver is not installed (or is not used)"

output of `xinput list` is:
root@alok-PORTEGE-R30-A:/home/alok# xinput  list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]

output of `synclient -l` is:
root@alok-PORTEGE-R30-A:/home/alok# synclient -l
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

xserver log and dmesg dont have trace of synaptics. kindly tell me how to solve this problem?

I found some solution from google but none are working for me [Synaptics drivers are not loading on Kubuntu 13.10 on Dell Vostro 2420](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397677/synaptics-drivers-are-not-loading-on-kubuntu-13-10-on-dell-vostro-2420)
 and https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?66624-Touchpad-options-not-available-in-system-settings

Comment: Related and useful - http://askubuntu.com/questions/127757/how-do-i-make-modprobe-changes-permanent/127761#127761

Comment: thanks @ElderGeek 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/127757/how-do-i-make-modprobe-changes-permanent/127761#127761 did not worked for me. I tried running `modprobe -r psmouse` and `modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

Comment: What happened? "did not work for me" doesn't provide any clues at all to me (blame me).

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) to 15.04 with
kernel 3.19
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 1.8

This solved the touchpad problem and I had no further trouble in higher versions (after 14.10). The touchpad worked well in 15.04, 15.10, 16.04, 16.10, 17.04.

Comment: yes its working fine for lter versions. Thanks :)
I have updated answer.